# Найти карусель для angularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, carousel

Есть отличный плагин slick, даже есть дериктива для angular, но он не работает с моделями. Кто что использовал, поделитесь. Нужна карусель чтоб несколько слайдов было на активной странице, и чтоб была возможность вставить не только картинку но и любые html элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Мы используем [OwlCarousel2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) с небольшой директивой-обёрткой.
Вызов получается такой

```
<ul owl-carousel owl-options="owlOptions">
  <li class="item owl-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
     <!-- content -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

UPD:
В директиве по таймауту вызываем, примерно так

```
app.directive('owlCarousel', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                owlOptions: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function () {
                     // ...
                     var owl = $(element).owlCarousel(scope.owlOptions);
                     // ...
                });
         };
}]);
```

Comment: А в какой момент вы делаете это $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel() ? Каждый раз когда меняются данные? или один раз при инициализации?

Comment: По таймауту вызываем. Обновил ответ.

Comment: а это хорошая практика использовать тайм-аут?

Comment: Я бы сказал - частая. Особенно, когда нужно сделать безопасный $apply (хоть сейчас есть и $applyAsync, но иногда нужен именно таймайт).

Answer (score 0):

Я использую slick. Ничего лучше сам не находил. В крайнем случае юзай Jquery.

Comment: Пробовал брать обычный slick, получаю данные, через ng-repeat добавляю их в DOM(все появляется на странице), затем вызываю $('.lenta').slick(); Но ничего не работает.